# Odata Client Code Generator-Unable to generate .cs file

Tags: odata, asp.net-web-api2

I have a WPF clinet and I am using **Odata Client Code Generator** for creating a client of an odata service using **Web Api 2**.

I have followed this tutorial:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/odatateam/archive/2014/03/12/how-to-use-odata-client-code-generator-to-generate-client-side-proxy-class.aspxd

The problem is that I am getting an **empty** **.cs** file that is being created by following the steps described in the tutorial(the link of which is given above).

The **MatadataDocumentUri** that I am using is: http://localhost:56045/odata

Is there something I am missing?

Here is the **Metadata** by using http://localhost:56045/odata/$metadata:

```
<edmx:Edmx xmlns:edmx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/06/edmx" Version="1.0">
<edmx:DataServices xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" m:DataServiceVersion="3.0" m:MaxDataServiceVersion="3.0">
<Schema xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edm" Namespace="RestApiServer.Models">
<EntityType Name="User">
<Key>
<PropertyRef Name="UserId"/>
</Key>
<Property Name="UserId" Type="Edm.Int32" Nullable="false"/>
<Property Name="UserName" Type="Edm.String"/>
<Property Name="UserType" Type="Edm.String"/>
<NavigationProperty Name="UserAddress" Relationship="RestApiServer.Models.RestApiServer_Models_User_UserAddress_RestApiServer_Models_UserAddress_UserAddressPartner" ToRole="UserAddress" FromRole="UserAddressPartner"/>
</EntityType>
<EntityType Name="UserAddress">
<Property Name="UserId" Type="Edm.Int32" Nullable="false"/>
<Property Name="UserAddress1" Type="Edm.String"/>
<NavigationProperty Name="User" Relationship="RestApiServer.Models.RestApiServer_Models_UserAddress_User_RestApiServer_Models_User_UserPartner" ToRole="User" FromRole="UserPartner"/>
</EntityType>
<Association Name="RestApiServer_Models_User_UserAddress_RestApiServer_Models_UserAddress_UserAddressPartner">
<End Type="RestApiServer.Models.UserAddress" Role="UserAddress" Multiplicity="0..1"/>
<End Type="RestApiServer.Models.User" Role="UserAddressPartner" Multiplicity="0..1"/>
</Association>
<Association Name="RestApiServer_Models_UserAddress_User_RestApiServer_Models_User_UserPartner">
<End Type="RestApiServer.Models.User" Role="User" Multiplicity="0..1"/>
<End Type="RestApiServer.Models.UserAddress" Role="UserPartner" Multiplicity="0..1"/>
</Association>
</Schema>
<Schema xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edm" Namespace="Default">
<EntityContainer Name="Container" m:IsDefaultEntityContainer="true">
<EntitySet Name="Users" EntityType="RestApiServer.Models.User"/>
<EntitySet Name="UserAddresses" EntityType="RestApiServer.Models.UserAddress"/>
<AssociationSet Name="RestApiServer_Models_User_UserAddress_RestApiServer_Models_UserAddress_UserAddressPartnerSet" Association="RestApiServer.Models.RestApiServer_Models_User_UserAddress_RestApiServer_Models_UserAddress_UserAddressPartner">
<End Role="UserAddressPartner" EntitySet="Users"/>
<End Role="UserAddress" EntitySet="UserAddresses"/>
</AssociationSet>
<AssociationSet Name="RestApiServer_Models_UserAddress_User_RestApiServer_Models_User_UserPartnerSet" Association="RestApiServer.Models.RestApiServer_Models_UserAddress_User_RestApiServer_Models_User_UserPartner">
<End Role="UserPartner" EntitySet="UserAddresses"/>
<End Role="User" EntitySet="Users"/>
</AssociationSet>
</EntityContainer>
</Schema>
</edmx:DataServices>
</edmx:Edmx>
```

Comment: Can you check if http://localhost:56045/odata/$metadata is accessible in your service? The tool is actually use ~/$metadata to generate the proxy file.

Comment: Hi zoe,
Yes it is accessible in my service. But when I used it as the **MetadataDocumentUri** the **.cs** file that is  generated, contains a few lines of commented statements nothing else.

Comment: Do you get any error or warning when generating the cs file? Can you check your vs output? Or can you post your metadata here? I can give a try.

Comment: There is no error but I get a warning i.e. **Running transformation: The element 'edmx:Edmx' was unexpected for the root element. The root element should be Edmx.**

Comment: Your service is based on OData v3 or v4? The code gen only supports V4. Can you post your metadata here? There are many reasons that can cause the codegen to fail, so it would be easier to debug if having the metadata.

Comment: I have the same error when trying to generate the client for OData V3 service, so can you please check your service version?

Comment: I'm using version 4. And I had also edited the post and  posted the metadata.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your metadata is actually a V3 format metadata. Please check:
http://services.odata.org/V4/OData/OData.svc/$metadata, the root is:

```
<edmx:Edmx xmlns:edmx="http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/edmx" Version="4.0">
```

and for http://services.odata.org/V3/OData/OData.svc/$metadata

```
<edmx:Edmx xmlns:edmx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/06/edmx" Version="1.0">
```

So your service is actually a OData V3 service, which our client generator does not support yet.

Comment: I had used **Add Controller** scaffolding to create controller. So does it means that there is no scaffolding for V4. ??

Comment: There is scaffolding for V4. http://odata.github.io/WebApi/#11-01-OData-V4-Web-API-Scaffolding. Not sure if it meets your requirement.

Comment: Thanx a lot zoe for your time . :)